# spring batch - create new file after writing fixed number of files

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I using org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader to read from the DB. In my row mapper I can determine the number of rows processed and written to the flat file public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum). The idea is to write to a new file using the same FlatFileItemWriter for the next X number of records. I can only write X records to a file. How do I achieve this file rolling using spinrg batch ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should look into the `MultiResourceItemWriter`, but I would not leverage the `RowMapper` to switch your resource.

This older question provides some insight on how you'd switch from one `Resource` (file) to another: [How to set the resource of MultiResourceItemWriter dynamically from ItemReader in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353531/)