# Spring batch to write multiple XML files using MultiResourceItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am new to Spring batch and trying to write multiple XML files for each record that I am going to read from database table. Suppose if I read 10 records, I need to create 10 XML files. One for each record.
The name for each XML file should be unique. For that, I am planning to use "column_name1" value but I am not sure how to achieve that. If anyone can help me in this then that would be a great help.

**Updated**:

Added the #{formsPMVRowMapper.id} to resource property which can point to DefaultOutboundIFMRowMapper(Custom implementation of RowMapper) where I created a class level variable to set the row id. but still it's not working since it tries to call getter of ID even before getting into mapRow method which I think correct behviour but I am not sure how to get hold of that ID which I can use as resource name for my file in multiXmlFileItemWriter. 
Could someone please let me know what could be the possibly correct way to do this?

Below is my Spring batch configuration file.

```
    <util:properties id="batchProperties">
        <prop key="batch.output.file">${outbound.pmv.filename}</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="itemReader" parent="pagingItemReader">
        <property name="queryProvider" ref="outboundQueryProvider" />
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="pmvRowMapper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pmvRowMapper"
        class="tx.oag.cs.txcses.arch.batch.readers.DefaultOutboundIFMRowMapper">
        <property name="idName" value="outbound_locate_record_staging_id" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="outboundQueryProvider" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="selectClause"
            value="select column_name1" />
        <property name="fromClause" value="from table_name" />
        <property name="whereClause"
            value="where column_name1='AAA' and column_name1='bbbb'" />
        <property name="sortKey" value="column_name1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="batchProcessor" parent="outboundStagingBatchProcessor">
        <property name="entityClass"
            value="Class_Name" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemWriter" parent="multiXmlFileItemWriter"/>

    <bean id="multiXmlFileItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="${outbound.ifm.outbound}/#{pmvRowMapper.id}"> 
    </property>         
    <property name="delegate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
            <property name="marshaller">
                <bean class="tx.oag.cs.txcses.arch.batch.utils.XMLStringMarshaller" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="itemCountLimitPerResource" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"
            value="classpath:config/env/#{@env}/batch-outbound.properties" />
        <property name="properties" ref="batchProperties" />
        <property name="localOverride" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

I understand that above "resource" property can only write files with same name but I am not sure how to use "resource" property well in co-ordination with "resourceSuffixCreator" property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the resource of MultiResourceItemWriter dynamically from ItemReader in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353531/how-to-set-the-resource-of-multiresourceitemwriter-dynamically-from-itemreader-i)

Comment: I saw this link before asking the question but seems like he is marshalling the CSV content into Patent object so he has the hold of data. I don't know how to get the resultset values which I can later use in <property name="resource">. Could you please tell me if there is any way to do that? Thanks!