# Reading multiple files in a folder and parsing it and writing to another folder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch. My requirement is, I have a folder say D:\xyzfolder\source which is having 25 flat files. Using spring batch I need to read and implement some business logic and write all 25 files with the same name into a different folder say D:\xyzfolder\destination

Currently, I am using `MultiResourceItemReader` and reading all the 25 files from the source folder and I am able to write into a single file using `FlatFileItemWriter with  setResource(outputResource)` but my requirement is to write as 25 different files. Please suggest how to achieve the above requirement

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use case this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356050/4767829 suggests using a MultiResourceItemWriter in combination with an ItemWriteListener that dynamically sets the output resource for each item.